# (When) can you embed a closed map with finite discrete fibers into a (branched) cover?

Tags: gn.general-topology, manifolds, covering-spaces, branched-covers

Assume all spaces are topological manifolds. A branched cover is a continuous open map with discrete fibers. A finite branched cover is one with finite fibers.

**Questions.** Given closed map $X\to S$ with finite discrete fibers to a compact base, does it admit an open embedding $X\hookrightarrow Y$ into a finite branched cover $Y\to S$? If so, why? If not, what are some simple examples and obstructions?

Comment: Are you assuming everything is surjective? Or are you just taking a very liberal definition of branched cover?

Comment: @KevinCasto you can assume the bundles are surjective.

Comment: Ok. One brief comment is that since your map is closed and has compact fibers, it is proper, so in particular $X$ is compact

Comment: I think the basic thing you need to worry about is say $f(x) = x^3 - x$, $(-2,2) \to (-6,6)$. The image of an open set around a critical point won't be open (instead half-open). This doesn't happen for complex polynomials bc the "2-dimensionality" somehow prevents it. Can this example be embedded in a branched cover?

Comment: If you are happy embedding $S$ as well as $X$ (such that the restriction to $X$ gets taken to $S$), I think it's possible that analytic maps can be "complexified" in the way that my example obviously can be, and then you can apply the open mapping theorem. But that seems pretty different from what you want.

Comment: @KevinCasto I'm trying to get a feel for the topological analogue to Grothendieck's [formulation](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05K0) of Zariski's main theorem. If I understand correctly, ZMT says you can "complete" missing fibers until you get a branched cover, and I'm trying to understand when and why this should be possible for topological manifolds.

Comment: Topologically, projecting the graph of $x\mapsto x(x^2−1)$ to the $y$-axis is a bundle with the total space like an elongated reverse 'S' shape. Openness fails because branches suddenly disappear at the two ramification points, so it seems that adding a branch from each ramification point gives a branched cover. As you point out, the resulting embedding is not open. I wonder what ZMT does in this case...

Comment: I asked about the ZMT version separately [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/440911/69037).

Comment: Yeah sorry, to be clear this is something specific about $\mathbb R$, over $\mathbb C$ all polynomials are open maps. The point is that I think for $\mathbb R$, the notion of branched cover has to be different than just 'open map'.